# SQLite Error, can't find my syntax error. Code 1

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm trying to add a new item to my database and I'm getting this error message. I've tried everything I can think of. Is there anything I am messing up?

```
05-04 23:46:28.425: E/AndroidRuntime(1378): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-04 23:46:28.425: E/AndroidRuntime(1378): Process: com.nmass.makeupmethodology, PID: 1378
05-04 23:46:28.425: E/AndroidRuntime(1378): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.nmass.makeupmethodology/com.nmass.makeupmethodology.MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: Product_Name (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT _id, Product_Name, Type, Color, Brand, Pallet_Name, Prod_Pic, Swatch_Pic, Date_Purchased, Misc FROM Products
05-04 23:46:28.425: E/AndroidRuntime(1378):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
05-04 23:46:28.425: E/AndroidRuntime(1378):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
05-04 23:46:28.425: E/AndroidRuntime(1378):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
05-04 23:46:28.425: E/AndroidRuntime(1378):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
05-04 23:46:28.425: E/AndroidRuntime(1378):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-04 23:46:28.425: E/AndroidRuntime(1378):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
05-04 23:46:28.425: E/AndroidRuntime(1378):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
05-04 23:46:28.425: E/AndroidRuntime(1378):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-04 23:46:28.425: E/AndroidRuntime(1378):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-04 23:46:28.425: E/AndroidRuntime(1378):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
05-04 23:46:28.425: E/AndroidRuntime(1378):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
05-04 23:46:28.425: E/AndroidRuntime(1378):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-04 23:46:28.425: E/AndroidRuntime(1378): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: Product_Name (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT _id, Product_Name, Type, Color, Brand, Pallet_Name, Prod_Pic, Swatch_Pic, Date_Purchased, Misc FROM Products
05-04 23:46:28.425: E/AndroidRuntime(1378):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
```

This is the onClick method that actually submits the data and grabs them from the editTexts and things.

```
public void onSubmitClick(View view){

    productName = (EditText)findViewById(R.string.AddNew_editTextNameName);
    productPalletName = (EditText)findViewById(R.string.AddNew_editTextPalletName);
    productBrandName = (EditText)findViewById(R.string.AddNew_editTextBrandName);
    productDatePurchased = (EditText)findViewById(R.string.AddNew_editViewDatePurchasedName);
    productMisc = (EditText)findViewById(R.string.AddNew_editViewOtherName);

    productType = (Spinner)findViewById(R.string.AddNew_spinnerTypeName);
    productColor = (Spinner)findViewById(R.string.AddNew_spinnerColorCatName);


    ProductsDataSource datasource = new ProductsDataSource(this);
    datasource.open();

    if(isPallet){
        datasource.createProduct(productName.getText().toString(), productType.getId(), productColor.getId(),
                productBrandName.getText().toString(), productPalletName.getText().toString(), prodPath, swatchPath,
                productDatePurchased.getText().toString(), productMisc.getText().toString());
        datasource.close();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Creating New Product In Database", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else{

        datasource.createProduct(productName.getText().toString(), productType.getSelectedItemPosition(), productColor.getSelectedItemPosition(),
                productBrandName.getText().toString(), null, prodPath, swatchPath,
                productDatePurchased.getText().toString(), productMisc.getText().toString());
        datasource.close();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Creating New Product In Database", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    productListActivity();
    finish();
}
```

This is the method that actually creates the item. I use the database.insert, I created the SQL insert in an attempt to fix my problem.

```
public void createProduct(String productName, int productType, int productColor, String productBrand, 
            String productPalletName, String productProdPic, String productSwatchPic, String productDateOpened, String productMisc){

    ContentValues productValues = new ContentValues();
        //productValues.putNull(SQLiteHelper.colID);; //0 - written for order ease 
        productValues.put(SQLiteHelper.colName, productName); //1
        productValues.put(SQLiteHelper.colType, productType);//2
        productValues.put(SQLiteHelper.colPalletName, productPalletName); //3
        productValues.put(SQLiteHelper.colBrand, productBrand); //4
        productValues.put(SQLiteHelper.colColor,productColor);//5
        productValues.put(SQLiteHelper.colProdPic, productProdPic);//6
        productValues.put(SQLiteHelper.colSwatchPic, productSwatchPic); //7
        productValues.put(SQLiteHelper.colDate, productDateOpened); //8
        productValues.put(SQLiteHelper.colMisc, productMisc); //9

            // Inserting Row

            database.insert(productTable, null, productValues);
            database.close(); // Closing database connection 

    /*  database.execSQL("INSERT INTO "+ productTable + " (" + SQLiteHelper.colName + ","
        + SQLiteHelper.colType + "," + SQLiteHelper.colColor + "," + SQLiteHelper.colBrand + 
        "," + SQLiteHelper.colPalletName + "," + SQLiteHelper.colProdPic + "," + SQLiteHelper.colSwatchPic 
        + "," + SQLiteHelper.colDate + "," + SQLiteHelper.colMisc + ") VALUES ( '" + productName + "' , " + productType 
        + " , " + productColor + " ,'" + productBrand + "' , '" + productPalletName + "' , '" + productProdPic + "','" + 
        productSwatchPic + "'," + productDateOpened + ",'" + productMisc + "');");
        database.close();  */
    }
```

Here is another method it is referencing- it supplies the listview with a list of items

```
public Cursor getAllProduct() {
        List<Product> productsList = new ArrayList<Product>();

        Cursor cursor = database.query(SQLiteHelper.productTable,
                allColumns, null, null, null, null, null);

        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            Product product = cursorToProduct(cursor);
            productsList.add(product);
            cursor.moveToNext();        
            cursor.close();
        }
        return cursor;
    }
```

And in case you want it, here is the table creation

public class SQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

```
static final String dbName="MakeupMethodology";
static final String productTable="Products";
static final String colID="_id";
static final String colName="Product_Name";
static final String colType= "Type";
static final String colPalletName = "Pallet_Name";
static final String colBrand="Brand";
static final String colColor="Color";
static final String colProdPic="Prod_Pic";
static final String colSwatchPic = "Swatch_Pic";
static final String colDate = "Date_Purchased";
static final String colMisc = "Misc";
static final String CreateDatabase = 
        "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + productTable +" (" + colID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT , "+ colName + " TEXT NOT NULL , " 
        + colType + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + colPalletName + " TEXT , "+ colBrand + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + colColor + " TEXT NOT NULL, " 
        + colProdPic + " TEXT , " + colSwatchPic + " TEXT , " + colDate + " DATE NOT NULL , " + colMisc + " TEXT)";

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
```

Edit: I found a (beginners :( )typo somewhere and how I have a new error message. Its been updated where the old one was

EDIT: I can't answer my own question for another couple of hours, so I'll just put this here in case anyone has a similar issue:

If your database is acting weird and you're on an emulator, cleaning the workspace and restarting the emulator is not enough. DELETE THE WHOLE THING AND START FROM SCRATCH (if you've attached an sdcard image to the emulator you can keep it, just delete the emulator from your config menu and make a new one)

Comment: Please upload the variable declaration part of `productName` file

Comment: Done! I found a typo but now I'm getting another error message- I updated that as well

Comment: Do one thing, just delete your application and run a fresh version.

Comment: Is it possible for you to clear the app data (or uninstall, then reinstall the app)? I was suspecting that you changed the schema after creating the DB for the first time without updating the DB in the phone.

Comment: That was my first thought. I've tried cleaning the workspace and quitting the emulator. I'll delete the entire emulator and just make a new one.

Comment: Umm, cleaning the workspace and quitting the emulator *doesn't clear the app data* (recreating the emulator does though, but a bit overkill ;). Instead, just uninstall the app *from the emulator* next time. (Go to Settings-Manage App)

Comment: Lesson learned, I just remade the emulator because the stupid emulator attached to eclipse is soo freaking slow. I can't use any other kind because the virtual machine I develop on for school can't handle the graphics other ones involve.

Answer (score 0):

The log says it all: there's no column called `Product_Name`. That should tell you to:

- check if it's really there. if you're testing on an emulator or a rooted device with sqlite, try running `.schema Products` on a shell
- make sure you're updating your database version every time you run your app, if you're installing directly from eclipse. table definitions won't reflect unless the app detects that the database version is upgraded.